# How can I refer to converted Lead information?

Tags: salesforce, crm, soql, lead

I have created a Custom Button as below:

Display Type: List Button
Behaviour: Display in existing window wihtout sidebar or header
Content: URL

Details:

```
 ../a02/e? &00N2800000AaCYu={!Opportunity.Id}
 &CF00N2800000BHtdT={!Opportunity.Name} &CF00N2800000BHtdY={!Lead.Name}
 &00N2800000BHvSK={!Lead.Id} &retURL={!Opportunity.Id}
```

I am using this button to Create new custom object from Opportunity. I am trying to pass some of my original information from converted Lead to new object.
But above Bold codes will not provide any information. Although I still can use SOQL to extract information but I am not sure how to merge SOQL with this URL configurations. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this by using JavaScript:

Solution:

Behaviour: **Execute JavaScript**

Content Source: **OnClick JavaScript**

Details:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")} 

var myLead = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name From Lead where ConvertedOpportunityID  ='{!Opportunity.Id}' limit 1");

records = myLead.getArray("records"); 
var myLeadId = records[0].Id;
var myLeadName = records[0].Name;


window.parent.location.href = "../a02/e?" + 
                              "&00N2800000AaCYu=" + '{!Opportunity.Id}' + 
                              "&CF00N2800000BHtdT=" + '{!Opportunity.Name}' +
                              "&CF00N2800000BHtdY=" + myLeadName +
                              "&00N2800000BHvSK=" + myLeadId + 
                              "&retURL=" + '{!Opportunity.Id}' ;
```

I am still interested to find better answers.